# How to detect kafka connection issue and switchover to different cluster in spring-kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

We have app which runs active/passive mode and we have 2 kafka clusters which runs in active/active mode. What happens is, once in a while one of the kafka cluster needs to be shutdown for a period of time during maintenance so in this case if our app is active in datacenter1 and in the same datacenter kafka cluster is shutdown then we have to manually switch over to datacenter 2 kafka cluster in the app config to continue processing msgs(producer and consumer both). Is there a better way to detect if kafka cluster is down so switchover to different cluster dynamically/programatically in spring kafka lib?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the framework to perform that function.

Spring doesn't get notified of the disconnection.